# $X$ is random variable for which it is valid $E(X^{2})=E(X^{3})=E(X^{4})<\infty$. Prove that X is discrete random variable with values in {0,1}

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

I have problem with this task. Is it perhaps good to assume the opposite?
Any idea will be helpful, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Try think of a non-negative function (it will be a quartic) $f(x)$ such that $E[f(x)] = 0.$ Also, this is definitely a duplicate question and it should have been asked and answered before here.

Comment: Check that $X^2$ is almost surely constant. If $X = 0$ almost surely, done. Otherwise $|X| = a>0$ almost surely.This is incompatible with the assumption $E X^2 = E X^3$ unless $X = 1$ almost surely.

Answer (score 4):

**Here's a (detailed) hint:** first, if $\mathbb{E}[X^2] = 0$, you are done. *(Why?)*

If not, suppose you can find a polynomial of the form $P(X)$ with the following properties:

- $P$ has degree 4 and no degree-1 or degree-0 term: $P(x) = ax^2 + bx^3 + cx^4$
- $P(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$
- the only roots of $P$ are $0$ and $1$ (possibly multiple)
- $a+b+c=0$

Then *if* you can find such a polynomial $P$, then looking at $\mathbb{E}[P(X)]$ will allow you to conclude. Can you see why?

*Note:* If that helps finding it, without loss of generality you can assume $c=1$ *(why?)*

Comment: Interesting approach, but it's quite a bit more gimmicky than noting $\mathrm{Var}(X^2) = 0$, and then checking that $E[X^3] = E[X^2]$ implies $X\in \{0,1\}$ a.s.

Comment: @Clement C. I did it, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Andrew Fair -- I tried to give a general, extendable approach -- could be used for similar problems.